# preference of the key of B or Cb (also G#min and Abmin)

Tags: key, key-signatures, enharmonics

The debate of whether F# or Gb is a better key is very prominent, but I'd like to discuss the keys of B and Cb.

As a guitar player, I would much rather have the key of B to play in. As a trombonist, the same key makes me cringe wildly. And as a pianist I am impartial to both, although playing in Cb is more comfortable and easier with accidentals.

String players have told me that they would rather play in B, and that seems reasonable to me, as a guitar player myself I can understand that string players often prefer to play with sharps instead of flats in their repertoire.

The brass players I've talked to have told me that, while they fully expect a chart to be written in B major, they would much rather play in the key of Cb major.

I have also had this discussion with my piano teacher, when pitting G# minor against Ab minor. I don't know how common each key is, but he did say that he prefers Ab minor, and the biggest reason why is that when you have a dominant seventh in the key of G#m, it's D#7 which has a nasty Fx. Compare that to the more lenient Eb7 of Abm.

What are your thoughts? I assume that in a popularity contest, because Cb is such an obscure key, B will win, but I wanted thoughts on the playability, practicality and convenience of each.

** I am talking in the context of 12-TET, and not an other tuning where the difference between two semitones is varied for each key.

- Quickly want to add that in most orchestral music that is in the key of B major, if there is a harp part for it it would be written in Cb, as it is considered the home key of the instrument.

Comment: By ”playing” do you mean reading music, or is there a difference for playing by ear too ?

Comment: @piiperi Seeing as the OP's established the context of 12-equal temperament, we're comparing different notations for the same pitches. So how would that affect playing by ear?

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica - playing by ear, I think most players won't necessarily be thinking in a key, but if they do, yes, good point.

Comment: For a lot of people, writing a piece in either Bb or C would be a better bet, but wonder how that would affect some listeners. It probably would affect players adversly. But if someone with absolute pitch was introduced to a new piece in Bb or C instead, what difference would it make? None?

Comment: @Tim If you have an awareness of where the tonic is, then you're playing in a key. But if you don't sense where tonic is, then how do you play anything, without a point of reference?

Comment: @Rosie I don't know, that's why I asked. Or does the OP use the word "play" as a synonym for "read"? Maybe.

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica - it depends on what instrument I'm playing. On bass, for example, I may well establish 'the key' as 'that fret on that string'. It doesn't necessarily have to have a name. I know the name, but it doesn't come into the equation. Example - in key A, I feel things go up a 4th. I don't think '4th of E is A, so find A.' I just move across a string. Maybe different on keyboard.

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica I do indeed refer to reading music, but I guess there could be a diference for playing by ear too, if there was it would probably depend on how often they hear this specific key as "Cb" or "B". Just a guess, though.

Answer (score 2):

Brass players are more at home in flat keys because their instruments are built that way: with fundamentals of F, Bb and Eb. (Yes, I know: trumpets in A, C and D, trombones in G and probably others also exist!) Guitars have a slight bias towards the sharp side. (Yes, I know: capos!)

On a piano any key is fine, but I can't think of a piece in Cb. Can anyone? Plenty of pieces *visit* Cb (Bolcom's Graceful Ghost springs to mind) but they don't often start and end in it. So it's rather an unfamiliar key. I could play scales of Cb faster thinking of them as B!

If it was *at all* interesting a piece of music in seven flats would soon need double flats, and along with the double-flat signs there would be the signs to *cancel* the double and return to single-flat. Big chords with mixtures of those accidentals are a pain to sight-read: the bars get cluttered, like a street full of bike lanes and No Right Turns.

It's odd that Cb major is such a warm, squashy key when B major is such a glittery one.

Comment: How to explain your last para? Would you have to *know* which key it was to get a warm, squashy OR a glittery feeling..?

Comment: A very interesting question @Tim. As a pianist, there's definitely a psychological difference between extreme sharp keys and their enharmonic flat equivalents. I was told by my teacher that a professor at one of the academies asked a teacher to get their pupils to learn the Bach C# major prelude and fugue - but to get half of them to learn it in Db (it's sometimes published in that key). He was able to tell when listening to their performances which key they had learnt it in without knowing in advance.

Comment: @Peter - Would it be because the pupils' mistake rate was higher in one of C sharp major or D flat major?

Comment: @Dekkadeci I doubt it - these were academy students. It's more to do with how you play it. In C# I would use a more staccato touch. But it was a long time ago - I heard about it in the early 1960s and it was old then.

Comment: @Peter Yes - I'd play it with more staccato too, though I'm not sure why. (Perhaps because C# is colder and more fragile, Tim!) I hadn't heard that story about the students and Bach since the early 70's. Excellent!

Comment: @Tim  I once saw a simplified version of the Moonlight Sonata. It was intended for beginners and had been transposed from C#m to Cm. It was oddly shocking to see. Beethoven loved Cm, but he would *never* have written that piece in that key. Cm was for other stuff. The reasons for seeing the keys as having unique qualities are many and varied. 'Classical' music often has the key in the tiltle, so you are told before it starts that, for example, Tchaik's 4th is in Fm before a note is played. Listen to - and play - enough music and you get a feeling for what the keys have meant over the years...

Comment: @Tim there is the concept of sharper keys being "brighter" and flatter keys "darker"; when traveling around the circle of fifths each on the sharp side the keys tend to get "brighter" and the opposite seems to get darker. But it definitely feels like more of a psychological concept.

Comment: @Lars - are you sure you meant psychological and not psychiatric (or most other words beginning with psy..? In 12tet all things are equal... So, when you finally get to the other side, I guess they cancel each other out!

Comment: @Tim ... Some people have suggested it all dates from the time before equal temperament, when one key really *was* different from another. I don't know if that's true, but musicians - jazz as well as classical - tend to agree about the different qualities of the keys. I haven't got perfect pitch. (Thank goodness! As a composer I regularly have to write for transposing instruments, which is easier without it) But all our lives we hear musicians playing with this understanding of, say, the bucolic quality of F major, and it stays with us. We associate bucolic music with F and vice versa.

Comment: @Lars Clearly music modulating to the sharp side generally feels brighter because a note has been sharpened: we are lifted into the new key. In the other direction, when a note is flattened, we relax or settle or feel resigned. Countless hymns do this, rising at the end of the second line and then falling back again. It's a different thing.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian - I'm sceptical. Many's te time, before digital tuners, we had to tune to whatever - sometimes a piano at a gig migt have been a quarter tone out. Where did that put the music? I'm not sure if we then played i sharp or flat keys, unknowingly. Point is, the numbers didn't sound or feel any different. And surely, in just temperament or other, one key would have been the best, with each successive key round the circle getting progressively more out of tune. *That* would make differences!

Comment: @Tim - Maybe it's because of my absolute pitch, but music in quarter-tone keys or close enough often comes off as unnerving to me. Boss themes like "Rude Buster" from *Deltarune* (key is between F sharp minor and G minor) and the *Final Fantasy Mystic Quest* regular boss theme (key is between B minor and C minor from what I've listened to) tend to be fine because unnerving boss themes are typical enough, but a studio recording of "Root Beer Rag" threw me for a complete loop because it was in between C major and D flat major (while I believe I first heard the piece in C major).

Comment: @Dekkadeci - interesting! Key question (please excuse pun...) What is your absolute pitch in - 440Hz, or something different?

Comment: @Tim - Yup, it's in A440.

Comment: @Tim: As an introduction to what historical tunings can do relating to Beethoven, I might suggest a listen to the CD "Beethoven in the Temperaments" (Enid Katahn, pianist). These are played on a modern concert grand, but using tunings that were common around Beethoven's time. Observe the perfect "flatness" and placidity of the opening of the Waldstein with a C major chord more in-tune than equal temperament, vs. the "buzz" and liveliness of the dim. sevenths at the opening of the Pathetique with more unequal thirds. Historical composers appreciated the differences among less "in-tune" keys.

Comment: @Tim Are you sceptical about musicians agreeing about the 'colours' of different keys? Or about composers writing certain types of music for certain keys? [About the quarter-flat insts:] I don't know what kind of band or orch you're talking about, or what kind of music they were playing, but I think orch and jazz musicians would still have played something written in E more brightly than something in Db. And 'A' wasn't always 440 of course. We don't know exactly what kind of 'well temperaments' Bach wrote for, but I'm sure, as Athanasus suggests, he enjoyed the differences between the keys.

Comment: @Athanasius It was quite hard to find but I just downloaded that CD from CDBaby. Thanks for mentioning it. Yes - the extreme in-tuneness has a

Comment: @OldBrixtonian: I think the end of your comment was cut off, but I hope you enjoyed it. I haven't listened to the CD in several years, but my recollection is that the performances were not necessarily my preferred ones, but the tuning was intriguing. Since the time that CD was released (late 90s), there have been a lot of releases of such music played on 19th century or 18th century pianos, usually in appropriate temperaments.  But putting those temperaments on a modern concert grand makes them stand out a bit more to my ear, which is why I thought of that specific album in this discussion.

Comment: @Athanasius Yes. I got interrupted!  I've listened to Moonlight and Waldstein so far and I think they gain a lot played with those tunings: there is a *reason* for Beethoven's wanderings. Yes - that C major chord is extremely still, isn't it? Inert. The minor 9th dissonances in the 1st mov't of the Moonlight are more beautiful and limpid. It's like hearing this music with shiny new ears!

Comment: @Athanasius Maybe you're right about the perfomances, I like its precision and its playfulness, but the pedalling is unusual in places. Btw,I would be interested in any recordings you know of using more extreme historical tunings. I used to be on a mailing list of academics and composers studying and experimenting with this stuff and have written a number of pieces in some outlandish tunings. There were two schools of thought among the composers there: 1) At the start of a piece, slide the most out-of-tune notes in *gradually* so that listeners can adjust to them. 2) Hit 'em between the eyes!

Comment: @OldBrixtonian: This discussion is perhaps going on too long in comments, but regarding recordings with more extreme historical tunings -- the easiest ones to find are often those played on old organs, which are often maintained in some variety of meantone tuning.  There are a lot of recordings of 17th-century repertory (e.g., Frescobaldi, Froberger, Buxtehude) played on various organs. Chromatic music often sounds quite wild, but when you get a cadence on a nice plain C major chord or something, the contrast is amazing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103211/discussion-between-old-brixtonian-and-athanasius).

Comment: @OldBrixtonian I heard that story at school - in the early 1960s. It's all psychological. One thinks of flats as "sinking" and sharps as "rising".

Comment: @Peter  Hi Peter. Sorry - I'm not sure which of my comments you were commenting on! What did I say? What story?

Comment: @OldBrixtonian Jan 10 17:48. I think it happened before the 2nd World War somewhere in England.

Comment: @Peter Oh Ok. Thanks. Yes, that seems likely. Btw, when you say it's all psychological, do you mean you don't believe the story of the professor?

Comment: I believe it totally. I meant that it's the psychology of the performer. So the listener can pick up the different style of playing (smoother vs. spikier etc.).

Answer (score 2):

I much favour keys with small accidental count.

In this case:

Cb has 40% extra accidentals with respect to B. Those extra accidentals are millions of times rustier inside my brain than for example the tone Bb, as I never use them (other than literally as accidentals, i.e. passing tones or other melodic devices). As a result, the difficulty increases much more than by this 40%.

As you add accidentals one by one (for example, keys C, F, Bb...), the difficulty delta is higher, because the accidental added is less and less common. The tone Bb is present in plenty of key signatures... the tone Db (for example) is present in very few of them.

That's me...

Answer (score 0):

As a saxophone player (it's a monophonic instrument, so I am largely unaffected by chords, unless I am playing multiphonics or "virtual" chords in my head during solos), I found it slightly easier to play key signatures that have flats rather than sharps when I was a beginner, because of the mechanics of my instrument. To give you an example (pictures taken from [The Woodwind Fingering Guide](https://www.wfg.woodwind.org/sax/sax_alt_1.html), I flipped them for your convenience, so that you can see which keys are higher and which are lower on the instrument when it is played; blacked-out keys on the diagram represent those that are pressed):

A4: [image: A4 tenor sax]
A♭4/G#4: [image: A♭4/G#4 tenor sax]
G4: [image: G4 tenor sax]

Explaining the example... If I am moving from A4 (a higher note in terms of sound) to A♭4 (a lower one), I have to press 2 more keys below A4, so my downward motion reflects the equivalent motion in sound. If I am going from G4 (a lower note) to G#4 (a higher one), I have to counterintuitively press 1 more key **below** G4, contrary to the motion in sound.

There are, naturally, some exceptions to this:

- the more "unusual" notes like C♭4 (enharmonic of B4, upward motion on the instrument) and E#4 (enharmonic of F4, upward motion)
- low-end notes requiring the left little finger (B♭3, B3 and C#3; the left hand is above the right on the saxophone, but it doesn't feel as much of an upward motion, because it's handled by the little finger when all the fingers on the right hand are already down, which makes it feel more like a "cherry on top" than an actual proper movement)
- some upper-register and altissimo notes
- some of the more unorthodox trill, alternative and microtonal fingerings

But, overall, as a saxophonist you quickly learn that playing a flat means going down the instrument, towards the bell, and playing sharps involves (at least for me) some mental gymnastics (they become less and less problematic with time) that translate sharps into flats. I still find it easier to play scales descending and play the occasional D4 instead of an F4 when I see an E#4 and am very tired/drunk. Your mileage may vary though.

I think that might be the case for many instruments that do not use a linear structure (like the piano) or a matrix (like guitar) to represent notes. To all oboe players out there: I can feel your pain.

P.S. My personal "favourite" on the saxophone is D#4 → E#4, which involves lowering/lifting 3 fingers to go down/up 1 tone, 1 "unnecessary" accidental (F natural is so much nicer than E#) and a note (D#) which likes to sound muffled/split in the 2nd octave of the instrument's "normal" range. If you are exhausted and trying to translate sharps into flats while playing a fast passage involving this switch, you can miss the timing or play something else note-wise entirely (if this switch is for the 3rd octave of the instrument's "normal" range, it becomes even more problematic and is considered one of the most difficult ones for the instrument, so you really don't want to play it with "unnecessary" sharps).

**Update**: this information is based on my personal experiences of playing "regular" B♭ and E♭ saxophones. There are horns out there that feature a linear fingering design.